# Trick to access to a function defined inside the load scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

My [Code](http://jsfiddle.net/DW55V/) :

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction(this)">Call Function</a>​

$(window).load(function () {
    function myFunction(param) {
        console.log("called");
    }
});
```

as you can see, I can't access to that function (is inside the load scope). I can't also use handlers inside the load, because I'm in a scenario where (don't ask me why, it's a google maps infowindow policy) handlers will be deleted when I create some element (so, where I should invoke that function from an object).

So, is there a "trick" to call a function inside the load scope?

Comment: am I missing something? why not create the function outside of the load scope?

Comment: You just seem to be declaring the function inside window.load.. So why not move it outside.. >>

Comment: problem is either the ultra simple solutin provided, or you have grossly over simplified the example... and all the other parts of question ramble around too much to really follow

Answer (score 2):

You can declare it as a variable outside the scope of the load function, and the set the value inside the scope of the load function, and it will be accessible, but it will only call the function after the variable is set i.e. after the load function has executed :

```
var myFunction;

$(window).load(function () {
    myFunction = function(param) {
        console.log("called");
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/KQJSq/)

Or how I'd do it:

```
<a href="#" id="myAnchor">Call Function</a>​
```

--

```
$(function() {
    $("#anchor").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();  
        console.log("called");
    });
});
```

Google maps have their own way of handling this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(event) { ...
```

Comment: while it works, what is the point?  I'd be interested to know if there is an advantage to coding this way, or is this just a workaround?

Comment: I would'nt do it myself, as I seems like a strange way to do things? I'd rather just attach a click handler to the anchor and not use inline JS, problem solved!

Comment: true, I was just curious.  Yeah unfortunately it seems he can not use load handlers.  I just assumed my method of declaring the function outside the load would be the preferred method (if not using handlers), am I wrong?

Comment: I'm assuming he needs to access things after they are loaded, so yes, declaring a function outside of load scope, generally causes problems

Comment: I've created a bunch of Google maps, with custom styles, clicking on markers bring up dialogs, popups, custom stuff, you name it, and I've yet had a problem with a click function defined with the native Google style, nor have I ever used jQuery's load function with a Google map, as all you have to do is create an event listener with some event bound to a marker or something else on the map, and do whatever you like in the function.

Answer (score 0):

why not do this?

```
function myFunction(param) {
    console.log("called");
}

$(window).load(function () {
    //Any code you actually need in the load
});
```

Comment: Because on myFunction() I manage some vars that are visibles only into load function.